# Flutter: Escape dollar sign '$' character in strings

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue facing me on a string in Flutter, specifically in a URL that includes '$' char.

Is there any way to escape the dollar sign `$`?

```
var url = Uri.parse('https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/Expectativas/versao/v1/odata/ExpectativaMercadoMensais?$top=100&$skip=0&$orderby=Data%20desc&$format=json&$select=Indicador,DataReferencia,Mediana,baseCalculo');
```

Comment: Explain 'the issue'.

Comment: If you have a `String` literal that you want to contain a literal `$` character, then you either need to escape it by preceding the `$` with a ```\``` (e.g. ```'\$'```) or use a *raw* string by preceding the literal with an `r` prefix (e.g. `r'$'`).

Comment: That sign is not called `dollar` sign. Its called `VALUE` sign

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dart has something called [String Interpolation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#string-interpolation). Here's a snippet from the docs:

> To put the value of an expression inside a string, use `${expression}`. If the expression is an identifier, you can omit the `{}`.
>
> Here are some examples of using string interpolation:
>
> | String | Result |
> | --- | --- |
> | `'${3 + 2}'` | `'5'` |
> | `'${"word".toUpperCase()}'` | `'WORD'` |
> | `'$myObject'` | The value of myObject.toString() |

In your case, the URL string contains exactly the escape symbol `$` to make a String interpolation. Dart thinks all words after the `$` symbol are identifiers (variables, functions etc.) but it doesn't find them defined anywhere. To fix it just do what [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72622045/flutter-url-uri-including-character/72622470#comment128282706_72622045) suggested: Escape the `$` symbols like `\$` or prefix the string with `r` like below:

`r'https://...Mensais?$top=100&$skip=0&$orderby=...'`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead

```
var url = Uri.parse( 'https://olinda.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/Expectativas/versao/v1/odata/ExpectativaMercadoMensais?\$top=100&\$skip=0&\$orderby=Data%20desc&\$format=json&\$select=Indicador,DataReferencia,Mediana,baseCalculo');
```

Use a reverse slash to escape string